# RadDataForm: Can I set the editor type AutoCompleteInline to substring matching for the suggestion?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I use the RadDataForm and for one property I set the editor type to "AutoCompleteInline". When I start typing letters the suggestion show up - that's works fine. But the suggestions contains only labels where the phrase are start with the typed letters.

Example:

```
// dataform metadata
...
{
  'name': 'myVar',
  'editor': 'AutoCompleteInline',
  'valuesProvider': ['Blue moon', 'Red sun', 'Green river', 'Purple sky']
},
...
```

By typing "bl" the suggestion shows me "Blue moon", but by typing "moon" the suggestion is empty.

How can I set the matching to substring with a variable start point and not only from the beginning? In my example: I need "Blue moon" as suggestion when I type "moon".

Is there a flag to set the mode or can I set a function which are called for matching?

Comment: I don't think that's supported out of the box in RadDataForm, you might have to write a [custom adapter](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/AndroidControlsDoc/com/telerik/widget/dataform/visualization/editors/DataFormRadAutoCompleteEditor.html#setAdapter-com.telerik.widget.autocomplete.AutoCompleteAdapter-) to achieve that.

Comment: @Manoj thanks for your hint. I'm not sure at the moment how to implement my own adapter in TS. If i have a solution i'll post it here.